# How to include Plus sign in mod rewrite. I need + sign in rewritten url

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to use + character in URL. I'm using Apache with PHP.

`([A-Za-z0-9/_%-@\+]*)` doesn't work.

What I need is `www.domain.com/c++/` => `index.php?category=c++`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your URL is encoded, you need to escape the + because "+" in a url encoded is equal to a space.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm a newbie to mod rewrite. Please explain how?

Comment: My Experience is with Java and Ruby on Rails, I don't know PHP enough to give you code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Since + or `%2B` indicates a space. So escape `\char` the "+".

```
www.domain.com/c++/
```

to

```
www.domain.com/c\%2B\%2B/
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Guide me to get a working rewrite rule. What you said is right. But where should i change like that?